# Unable to start rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to start rails server using `rails s` command. But i'm getting the following error:

```
A server is already running. Check repo/tmp/pids/server.pid.
```

I checked the file, but its blank. There is no id in the server.pid file. Then I tried to find out the process running on port 3000 using the command `lsof -wni tcp:3000`. It also does not show any id.

Then I tried starting the server on a different port using `rails s -p 3001`, but this also gives the same error. Please could someone explain what is going on.

Thanks

**EDIT:** does not work even after restarting computer

Comment: When you run `lsof -wni tcp:3000` does anything show up at all?

Comment: @nahtnam: No, nothing at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the file then:

```
 rm repo/tmp/pids/server.pid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command in your terminal window.

```
kill -9 $(lsof -i tcp:3000 -t)
```

If it doesn't work, you can always just restart your computer/server...

Comment: Wow, im not sure what is going on. Let me look around more.

Answer (score 0):

1- Use the command below for checking that how many server currently running

$ ps aux | grep rails

---

2- For killing the existing server

$ kill -9 pid